# Why don't movies show Windows?

Tags: windows, legal

I didn't know where to ask this, so I thought this could be the place to ask, if not I will delete it.

Why don't movies show Windows System on monitors that are shown in movies? I recall seeing it a couple of times maybe, but usually it's just some fake OS that does not exist, some other rare times it is Mac OS, still Mac is shown more than Windows I guess, but usually it's that fancy fake OS.

Why is that? is there something about Microsoft that prevents them? or is it because they do not want to advertise for Windows without getting paid? anything I am missing? they do not show fancy made up cars for example.

Comment: Or because filmmakers think that Windows isn't cool enough :)

Comment: Product placement is a huge business.  A movie studio isn't going to give Microsoft free advertising likewise Microsoft does not want a movie studio to present their product in way they don't approve of.  This question is out of scope for Superuser.  In nearly all cases every product, depicted in a movie, will be like this.

Comment: @FrankThomas cars are excluded? PC monitors are everywhere just like cars.. just thinking..

Comment: Did you try searching Google for this? The general consensus is that Apple is handing out free Macs/iPads etc. in return for product placement.

Comment: @James yes I did, otherwise I won't ask here. Anyway, nothing interesting or conclusive was found.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis, Cars are differant in that they are a physical manifestation of the protected material, and as such they are subject to the First Sale Doctrine, which allows a purchaser to use a good for any purpose they see fit. Thought you may get sued if your filmed useage is determined to be defamatory, it is still not a Intellectual property issue.

Comment: Windows can be seen in real films like documentaries (not on purpose but you can usually tell in documentaries that they are using Windows). In other films, it's a different story. Personally, I think Microsoft would enjoy the depiction

Answer (score 3):

See here for the MS terms of service to [display Windows in TV and Movies](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/permissions)
and here are their [Trademark guidelines](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/trademarks/usage/default.aspx).